# AFNetworking: How/when to prompt for username and password for BASIC Auth?

Tags: ios, cocoa, afnetworking, basic-authentication

I'm looking for a best-practice about prompting the user for credentials.  I have to code for the possibility that after the user logs in from the phone, he/she could login from another device or webpage and change the password.  Since I'm doing BASIC auth, that token will now be incorrect and I need to handle it appropriately.

I've started a new project with AFNetworking.  I have subclassed AFHTTPClient and I've overridden the HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest message to set a authentication challenge block on it after I make the call to super.  In that block I should create a new NSURLCredential object and send it back to the sender.  I get it so far.

What I don't get is how I'm supposed to prompt the user.  Ideally I'd like to push a login screen on my nav controller with a login button.  Clicking the login button would create the NSURLCredential and send it back to the sender.

- Should I somehow block inside the challenge block?  That doesn't seem right.
- Should I save the NSURLAuthenticationChallenge object to a global?  Eww.
- Should I push the login page from my subclassed AFHTTPClient?  Sounds like I'm violating separation of concerns.
- Should I call my AppDelegate to prompt the user and pass the NSURLAuthenticationChallenge object to it?  Sounds better, but still unsure.

Comment: So far, I'm going with option 4.  However, I had to push the login controller with a performOnMainSelector call.  It seems that causes a problem then when calling useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:.  My server shows no Authorization header.  I'm still stuck.